# Drawing a transparent line in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I need a way to draw a partially transparent line in pygame. I found this answer([python - Draw a transparent Line in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701453/python-draw-a-transparent-line-in-pygame)) but it only works with straight lines and doesn't work with different line thicknesses.

Comment: you can create new Surface with transparent background and draw any lines (without transparency) and later draw it in main Surface with transparency.

Comment: example from you link works in similar way as I described - but you don't have to use `fill()` but `draw.line()`

Comment: I'm new to pygame, how would you do this (with multiple surfaces)?

Comment: create surface as in exeampl and use `fill()` with color `(0,0,0,0)` to create transparent surface (important is last zero which means `alpha` channel), later draw on this surface any line(s) and finally blit it on main surface. I have some [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency). Minimal example uses `draw.circle` to draw transparent circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create new surface with any size and with `alpha` channel

```
surface = pygame.Surface((width, height)).convert_alpha()
```

or use main surface to create new surface with the same size

```
surface = screen.convert_alpha()
```

Fill it with transparent color `(0,0,0,0)`. Important is last zero which means `alpha` channel - `(R,G,B,A)`

```
surfaces.fill([0,0,0,0])
```

Draw on this surface with alpha channel smaller then `255`

```
pygame.draw.line(surface, (0, 0, 0, 32), (0, 0), (800, 600), 5)
```

And finally you can blit it on main page in any place

```
screen.blit(surface, (x, y))
```

For surface which has the same size as main surface it can be `(0,0)`

```
screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
```

---

Minimal example

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))#, depth=32)

surface1 = screen.convert_alpha()
surface1.fill([0,0,0,0])
pygame.draw.circle(surface1, (255, 0, 0, 128), (325, 250), 100)

surface2 = screen.convert_alpha()
surface2.fill([0,0,0,0])
pygame.draw.circle(surface2, (0, 255, 0, 128), (475, 250), 100)

surface3 = screen.convert_alpha()
surface3.fill([0,0,0,0])
pygame.draw.circle(surface3, (0, 0, 255, 128), (400, 350), 100)

surface4 = screen.convert_alpha()
surface4.fill([0,0,0,0])
pygame.draw.line(surface4, (0, 0, 0, 32), (0, 0), (800, 600), 5)
pygame.draw.line(surface4, (0, 0, 0, 32), (0, 600), (800, 0), 5)

surface5 = screen.convert_alpha()
surface5.fill([0,0,0,0])
pygame.draw.polygon(surface5, (255, 0, 0, 128), [(400, 250), (450, 300), (400, 350), (350, 300)])

screen.fill([255,255,255]) # white background
screen.blit(surface1, (0,0))
screen.blit(surface2, (0,0))
screen.blit(surface3, (0,0))
screen.blit(surface4, (0,0))
screen.blit(surface5, (0,0))

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

pygame.quit()
```

[image]